# Почему не работает .click() на вставленом через .append() html коде?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Клонирую форму для комментариев при помощи jquery, в форме есть кнопка для того что бы отменить(удалить форму), но на клонированной форме .click() не работает.

Сталкивался ли кто то с подобным? и как можно решить эту проблему?

```
var commentForm = $(".comments-form-reply").clone();

$(".comments-item-button-reply").click(function () {
    var commentId = $(this).closest(".comments-item").attr("id");
    var commentIdValue = Number(commentId.split('-').slice(1));
    $(".form-reply-js").remove();
    $("#" + commentId).append(commentForm);
    $("#" + commentId + " .comments-form-reply").addClass("form-reply-js");
    $("#" + commentId + " .comments-form-reply form").append('<input class="form-reply-js" type="hidden" name="parent_id" id="id_parent_id" value="' + commentIdValue + '">');
});

$(".btn-comment-reply-cancel").click(function () {
    $(".form-reply-js").remove();
    alert('work');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте подобную конструкцию:

```
$('body').on('click', '.comments-item-button-reply', function () { /* ... */ });
```

В данном случае все события клика будут слушаться на родительском элементе `body`, а потом уже будет идти проверка, что событие клика пришло именно на элемент `.comments-item-button-reply`.

Я рекомендую вам ради оптимизации заменить в моем примере `body` на более близкого родителя к вашему селектору, например, на обёртку блока комментариев.

Comment: а не проще ли после аппенда повешать слушатель и не разводить кашу из селекторов и листенеров?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, все работает